# dymamic text binding in a WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multilingual

Sorry for the noob question.... but
 I have a rather large unilingual application that I have to make multilingual, meaning no resource file. I don't have the option of using the culture information but need to do it more on the fly at runtime so that the user can change languages either on startup or menu pick while in the application. I can handle that part ok. I realise there are traditional ways to set these values but I'm hoping to find a better solution.

What I'd like to be able to do is the following

First of all is this even possible? I've taken a pretty good look around and didn't really find anything close to what I'd like to do. I would even be willing create a few user controls if that was the solution. In the end I'll have to do this for buttons, labels, datagrid headers and messages(these are easy lol)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The MSDN Docs - CultureInfo.CurrentCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Try this article: [Creating an Internationalized Wizard in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF).

Specifically look at the startup code for the application where CurrentCulture is modified for the CurrentThread.

Do not feel locked out of using per-culture resources by WPF.  Different resources can be used via the "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" as described in the article.